# Using PiTiVi to delete the middle of a video?

Tags: pitivi

I import a video into PiTiVi, drag it to the timeline, split the grouped A/V tracks at the start of where I want to delete and the end, then delete the middle.  The audio track does what I expect, but all the video that used to be there stays there, just playing at double speed or something.  I even tried just deleting the end of the video and only the end of the audio went away, the video stayed but played faster.  I thought it might be just the preview, but rendering the project produces these same results.

What am I doing wrong?

PiTiVi 0.13.5 on Maverick

Comment: What type of video file are you importing? Some of the more ugly (read: closed) file formats tend to make gstreamer (which PiTiVi uses) a little wonky. Have you tried another video format (like .ogv?)

Comment: The source is wmv.  So, should I try just converting it first and then importing?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).